# Facebook login button getting cutoff on Chrome

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

This is the mobile device testing mode in Google Chrome.

My Facebook like button is getting cut off:

[image]

All the pixel sizes are correct.

Answer (score 1):

The zoom level for an iframe (which is how the Facebook Login button is shown) in Chrome is not the same as the zoom level for the page itself.

Therefore you need to click on the button and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> to zoom out on just that iframe.

It can be tricky because clicking on it will trigger the popup, so you may need to use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to give it focus.

Note that opening Facebook in another window and zooming that to 100% also doesn't seem to be using the same zoom level - (even though the iframe appears to be the same domain).

This also only seems to be a problem with the mobile device testing tool.